# 'final_result' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/graph.pb'

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, tensorboard

> 'final_result' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/graph.pb'

Code from orignal source build and successfully run APK for default model.
but Unable to run custom model (tensorflow) on android using Android studio

org.tensorflow.demo

```
org.tensorflow.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 2955
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Node 'final_result' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/graph.pb'
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.graphOperation(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:171)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:106)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(ClassifierActivity.java:130)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity$1.onPreviewSizeChosen(CameraActivity.java:159)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(CameraConnectionFragment.java:421)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.openCamera(CameraConnectionFragment.java:428)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.access$000(CameraConnectionFragment.java:64)
                                                                   at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraConnectionFragment.java:95)
                                                                   at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:387)
                                                                   at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:325)
                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16065)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Im facing the same issue